# ASP.NET Web API: passing a list as param on GET request on POSTMAN

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to pass a list as query parameter in Postman.
[image]

Both "companies" and "branches" are lists of int, but when I debug my code in the Repository's method those parameters come back empty.

This is my code:

-Repository

```
public IList<Report> GetSackFractions(List<int> companies, List<int> branches, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
    {
        var query = @"SELECT * 
                      FROM sackReport";

        if (companies.Any())
            query += " WHERE sackReport.CompanyId IN (:companies) ";

        if (branches.Any())
            query += " AND sackReport.BaseId IN (:branches) ";

        query += " AND sackReport.[Date] BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo";

        return Session.CreateSQLQuery(query)
            .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Report>())
            .SetParameter("companies", companies)
            .SetParameter("branches", branches)
            .SetParameter("dateFrom", dateFrom)
            .SetParameter("dateTo", dateTo)
            .List<Report>();
    }
```

-Service

```
public IList<ReportVm> GetSackFractions(List<int> companies, List<int> branches, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
    {
        var sackFractionsResult = _ReportRepository.GetSackFractions(companies, branches, dateFrom, dateTo);
        return sackFractionsResult.Select(sackFraction => new ReportVm(sackFraction)).ToList();
    }
```

-Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorization]
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult GetSackFractions([FromQuery] List<int> companies, [FromQuery] List<int> branches, [FromQuery] DateTime dateFrom, [FromQuery] DateTime dateTo)
    {
        return Execute(() =>
        {
            var service = new ReportService(Repository);
            var sackFractions = service.GetSackFractions(companies, branches, dateFrom, dateTo);
            return new JsonResult(sackFractions);
        });
    }
```

I also tried using an array on integers instead (int[]) but it did not work.

I am not sure if I have an error on my code or in the postman call.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

your url should be like this

```
 ..../GetSackFractions?companies=1&companies=2&branches=3&branches=4
```

to reach it , just remove [0], [1] from keys in postman, make it just companies several times , and branches several times

```
companies 1
companies 2
branches 3
branches 4
```

or  just type an url like the one above

Comment: Thank you Serge. I removed [0] and [1] andI am getting this exception "Could not cast or convert from System.Int64 to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]" on my code on the Newtonsoft library. I am not sure why the request is sending the company data as int and not as list

Comment: @Claudia Can you show me your url now? is it the same as mine? I tested it in VS and everything is working properly.Did you check spelling?

Comment: This is my url: .../Api/Recycling/Report?companies=93&companies=262&branches=2455&branches=2862&dateFrom=2021-06-03&dateTo=2021-06-05.

Comment: @Claudia I just copied your data and your action header and tested it VS using Postman, everything is working properly.  I only see Report but it is GetSackFractions action in your question, does it have the same parameters?